# How to manage tablespace file size for a 1TB table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, percona

Question 1. Is it possible to control the size of the IBD file serving huge tables such as 1 TB tables?

Question 2. Is it possible to make the 1 TB table served by more than 1 *IBD files?

Comment: Keyword to search for: partitioning.

Comment: Do not use `PARTITION` without doing some research -- it provides no benefit in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

There's no option to set a limit on the size of a [file-per-table tablespace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html) or a [general tablespace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-tablespaces.html) in MySQL.

General tablespaces have an option for maximum size, but the option is for future implementation, and it's ignored in MySQL 5.7.

For the system tablespace (aka `ibdata`) you can specify a maximum size and don't make it autoextend. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-init-startup-configuration.html#innodb-startup-data-file-configuration for details.

If you want a single table to be stored in multiple tablespace files, you can use [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html) (as mentioned in the comment from @Shadow).

Comment: I think there is a hard limit of 64TB (or maybe 32TB).  Still, that is far more than you are asking about.